# GWT timer throwing exception while in a standalone class

Tags: java, gwt, timertask, gwtquery

I am using GWTQuery to detect `paste` event on a textbox, then setting a small timer after which it is supposed to get the value pasted in it. Something like this:

```
        $("#paste").live("paste",new Function() {
            public boolean f(Event e) {
                Timer t = new Timer() {
                    public void run() {
                        String text = paste.getText();
                        String oldtext = box.getText();
                        String oldsel = box.getSelectedText();
                        int oldpos = box.getCursorPos();
                        if (text.matches("^\\d+$")) {
                            box.setText(oldtext.substring(0,oldpos)+text+oldtext.substring(oldpos+oldsel.length(),oldtext.length()));
                            oldpos += text.length();
                        }
                        box.setReadOnly(false);
                        box.setFocus(true);
                        box.setCursorPos(oldpos);
                        paste.setText("");
                    }
                };
                t.schedule(5);

                return true;
            }
        });
```

When I include this in the main file (where the `onModuleLoad` is declared, that is, the the file which shows up in the browser), it works just as expected. However, I have compartmentalized the code, placing the textboxes in their own package and calling `initWidget` to import them in the main file. When I place this code in that class, I am getting error messge like `Uncaught exception escaped`, which points to something like 
`com.google.gwt.sample.myproject.client.Location$3$1.run`. Can anyone tell me what is wrong here, and how do I rectify it?

Comment: could you post more code? how is the widget instanciated, and the gquery code called.

Comment: This is the code. In the standalone imported class, I was adding a textbox named `paste` to the main panel (on which I am calling `initWidget`, to be imported into the main module) like `TextBox paste = new TextBox()`. Then I tried to apply the code above. It throws error. When I remove it and do something like `paste = $("#paste").widget(); $("#paste").live(...);`, it works fine...